# Use a regular iterator to iterate backwards, or struggle with reverse_iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I recently learned about the right way to work with reverse iterators in C++ (specifically when you need to erase one).  (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830158/how-to-call-erase-with-a-reverse-iterator) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404258/how-do-i-erase-a-reverseiterator-from-an-stl-data-structure).)

This is how you're supposed to do it:

```
typedef std::vector<int> IV;
for (IV::reverse_iterator rit = iv.rbegin(), rend = iv.rend();
     rit != rend; ++rit)
{
  // Use 'rit' if a reverse_iterator is good enough, e.g.,
  *rit += 10;
  // Use (rit + 1).base() if you need a regular iterator e.g.,
  iv.erase((rit + 1).base());
}
```

But I <strike>think</strike> thought this is much better (**Don't do this**, not standards compliant, as MooingDuck points out):

```
for (IV::iterator it = iv.end(), begin = iv.begin();
     it-- != begin; )
{
  // Use 'it' for anything you want
  *it += 10;
  iv.erase(it);
}
```

Cons:

- <strike>**You tell me.**  What's wrong with it?</strike>
- It's not standards compliant, as MooingDuck points out.  That pretty much overrules any of the possible advantages below.

Pros:

- Uses a familiar idiom for reverse for-loops
- Don't have to remember (or explain) the `+1`
- Less typing
- Works for std::list too: `it = il.erase(it);`
- If you erase an element, you don't have to adjust the iterator
- If you erase, you don't have to recompute the begin iterator

Comment: You mean besides the fact this is Undefined Behavior and will fail/crash in common situations?  Try it with an empty `map`.

Comment: care to elaborate in an answer?  Is the UB decrementing an input iterator or decrementing past the beginning?  Is it UB for all containers?

Comment: Can't decrement an input or output iterator (I forgot that one, good eye), and you also can't decrement past the beginning for any container.

Comment: Well that pretty much settles it huh?  I edited the question.

Comment: I just realized you can't use `std::reverse_iterator` on an input or output iterator either, so that's a moot point.  But it's still UB to iterate one before the beginning of any container.

Comment: The "can't decrement past the beginning of a container" issue can be easily avoided by doing `for (...; it != begin; ) { --it; ... }`, no?  Why mostly dismiss this question on that basis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for reverse iterators is that the [standard algorithms](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) do not know how to iterate over a collection backwards. For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
std::wstring foo(L"This is a test, with two letter a's involved.");
std::find(foo.begin(), foo.end(), L'a'); // Returns an iterator pointing
                                        // to the first a character.
std::find(foo.rbegin(), foo.rend(), L'a').base()-1; //Returns an iterator
                                                 // pointing to the last A.
std::find(foo.end(), foo.begin(), L'a'); //WRONG!! (Buffer overrun)
```

Use whichever iterator results in clearer code.

Comment: Good point that there may be some generic algos that will work on reverse_iterators and there may not be a 'reverse' version of that algo for use on regular iterators.  For wstring you could use find_last_of, but if it were some other type of container that's not an option.

Comment: BTW your second std::find() call returns an iterator pointing to '\'' (the apostrophe).  This points to the 'a': std::wstring::iterator iter = (std::find(foo.rbegin(), foo.rend(), 'a') + 1).base();

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, Scott Meyers' *Effective STL* recommends that you just stick with a regular ol' `iterator` (Item 26).

Comment: It also says to avoid explicit loops, and `reverse_iterator` is sometimes necessary to accomplish that. Item 26 is talking about explicit loops only.

Comment: Also, this implies that the OP's code is fine, when it is in fact, Undefined Behavior (and will fail in common situations)