# c++ STL copy_backward question

Tags: c++, stl

```
int main () {
  vector<int> myvector;
  vector<int>::iterator it;

  // set some values:
  for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
    myvector.push_back(i*10);          // myvector: 10 20 30 40 50

  myvector.resize(myvector.size()+3);  // allocate space for 3 more elements

  copy_backward ( myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+5, myvector.end() );

  cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    cout << " " << *it;

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Why the output is  "myvector contains: 10 20 30 10 20 30 40 50"

why not "30 40 50 10 20 30 40 50"

The implementation of copy_backward is here:

```
template<class BidirectionalIterator1, class BidirectionalIterator2>
  BidirectionalIterator2 copy_backward ( BidirectionalIterator1 first,
                                         BidirectionalIterator1 last,
                                         BidirectionalIterator2 result )
{
  while (last!=first) *(--result) = *(--last);
  return result;
}
```

So confused.
thank you for all your help.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853358/use-a-regular-iterator-to-iterate-backwards-or-struggle-with-reverse-iterator/1857314#1857314

Comment: Why do you expect the first three elements to be modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That output looks right to me according to the way the code is written.  You are copying from and into the same vector.  You are copying from [begin, begin +5] (10 20 30 40 50) and you are copying to [end, end-5].  So 10 20 30 [10 20 30 40 50] is the right output for that code.  The first 3 elements are untouched.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy something backwards, use reverse-iterators: `rbegin()` and `rend()`. Then just use the regular `std::copy`.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps. To be fair, I'm not sure exactly what the OP wants. Where would the data for the 'new' first three elements come from?